# Why can't I create a pointer to a TTreeNode in a TTreeView

Tags: c++builder-10.4-sydney, ttreenodes

Using C++ Builder in Rad Studio 10.4

Why can't I create a pointer to a `TTreeNode`?

I have a `TTreeView` called `BookmarksTree`, and I want to loop through all of its nodes. When I try and compile this:

```
TTreeNode *Node;
Node = BookmarksTree->Items[1];
```

I get a compiler error:

> assigning to 'Vcl::Comctrls::TTreeNode *' from incompatible type 'Vcl::Comctrls::TTreeNodes'

According to [Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.Items](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.Items), I should be able to use
`MyTreeNode = TreeView1->Items[[1]];`

Has anyone any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BookmarksTree->Items` is a pointer to a single [`TTreeNodes`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNodes) object.  You are trying to perform pointer arithmetic to access a node as if the `Items` were an array of `TTreeNode*` pointers, which is simply not the case.

You need to use the [`TTreeNodes::Item[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNodes.Item) sub-property instead, eg:

```
int count = BookmarksTree->Items->Count;
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    TTreeNode *Node = BookmarksTree->Items->Item[i];
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`TTreeNodes::operator[]`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNodes.operator_H5BH5D), but that requires you to dereference the `TTreeNodes*` pointer first, eg:

```
int count = BookmarksTree->Items->Count;
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    TTreeNode *Node = (*(BookmarksTree->Items))[i];
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, in the Clang-based compilers only, you can use C++ iterators, per [C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers), eg:

```
auto iter = std::begin(BookmarksTree->Items);
auto end = std::end(BookmarksTree->Items);

while (iter != end)
{
    TTreeNode *Node = *iter++;
    ...
}
```

Or a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (which uses iterators internally):

```
for(TTreeNode *Node : BookmarksTree->Items)
{
    ...
}
```